# customize BigTextStyle notification with ParsePushBroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform

I'm trying to override the getNotification() method of Parse ParsePushBroadcastReceiver class to render a BigTextStyle notification with two action buttons at the bottom. Sort of like:
http://developer.android.com/design/media/notifications_pattern_two_actions.png

According to the Parse push notification guide, that's all I need to do:

Here's my code:

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

private static final String LOG_TAG = NotificationReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected Notification getNotification(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "getNotification called");
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String jsonData = extras.getString("com.parse.Data");
    String url = "";
    String objectId = null;
    String title = "";
    String alertMsg = "";

    if (jsonData != null){
        try {
            JSONObject data = new JSONObject(jsonData);
            objectId = data.getString("objectId");
        }
        catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error parsing json data", e);
        }
    }
    else{
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "cannot find notification data");
    }

    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "notification for item with id=" + objectId);

    BucketListItem item = BucketListDao.getInstance().findById(objectId);
    title = "Get ready!";
    alertMsg = item.getSummary() + "\n" + item.getLocation() + "\n" + item.getStartTime();

    Intent detailsIntent = new Intent("com.parse.push.intent.OPEN", Uri.parse(url));
    PendingIntent piDetails = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, detailsIntent, 0);

    Intent snoozeIntent = new Intent(context, BucketListActivity.class);
    snoozeIntent.setAction("com.stubhublabs.dopamine.SNOOZE");
    PendingIntent piSnooze = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, snoozeIntent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(alertMsg)
                    .setContentIntent(piDetails)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL) // requires VIBRATE permission
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(alertMsg))
                    .addAction (R.drawable.ic_stat_snooze,
                            context.getString(R.string.notification_snooze), piSnooze)
                    .addAction (R.drawable.ic_stat_details,
                            context.getString(R.string.notification_details), piDetails);

        return builder.build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onPushOpen called");

        Intent i = new Intent(context, BucketListActivity.class);
        i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<? extends Activity> getActivity(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "getActivity called");
        return super.getActivity(context, intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onPushReceive called");
        super.onPushReceive(context, intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onReceive Called");
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}
```

The BigTextStyle notification does show up. But clicking on the notification or the action buttons doesn't do anything. And as the log shows, onPushOpen was never invoked:

```
10-08 15:03:28.776    4021-4021/ V/NotificationReceiver﹕ onReceive Called
10-08 15:03:28.776    4021-4021/ V/NotificationReceiver﹕ onPushReceive called
10-08 15:03:28.776    4021-4021/ V/NotificationReceiver﹕ getNotification called
10-08 15:03:28.776    4021-4021/ V/NotificationReceiver﹕ notification for item with id=yyw00Lh5Ce
```

If I don't use my extended ParsePushBroadcastReceiver class, or if I use my ParsePushBroadcastReceiver class but not overriding the getNotification method, the standard would render and clicking on it does open the intended activity.

I can't find any tutorial or example of extending ParsePushBroadcastReceiver to get custom notification. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set your content intent to:

```
Intent detailsIntent = new Intent("com.parse.push.intent.OPEN", Uri.parse(url));
PendingIntent piDetails = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, detailsIntent, 0);
```

This is the intent that is called when your notification is clicked. However, the `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver` is a `BroadcastReceiver`. If you want to reuse the infrastructure provided by Parse, you need to use `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` rather than `PendingIntent.getService()`.

Of course, you could just use `PendingIntent.getActivity()` and use the Intent you built in `onPushOpen()` and bypass that indirection completely.

Comment: getActivity() did the trick! (getService didn't work for some reason) Thanks a lot!

Comment: hmm... clicking the action button doesn't clear the notification from the status bar. Now I need to figure out how to get the notification id to cancel it. Doesn't look like ParsePushBroadcastReceiver is providing that.. :(

Comment: If you mean clicking on the notification doesn't clear it, then you can use [setAutoCancel()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setAutoCancel(boolean)). If you mean the actions, then you can pass in whatever extras you want to your Intent (such as the id) - just make sure you use `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` instead of `0` as the last parameter to `PendingIntent.getActivity()`/`PendingIntent.getService()` or your extras won't get updated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I meant the actions case. Problem for me was:
1. I uses Parse SDK to do the notify so I don't have access to the id of returned notification (as least I haven't figured out a way to access it)
2. One of my action on button click is to launch a browser (instead of opening my app) so I don't have a place to put in code to cancel/clear the notification from the status bar.

Comment: I reached character limit so I have to break it into two. continue from the comment above.
To solve 1, I used NotificationManager.cancelAll(). My understanding is that it will blindly cancel all notifications sent by my app, which is fine for me.

To solve 2, I had to create a proxy activity and have the action button launch the proxy activity which does nothing but 1. cancel the notification, 2 open the browser, 3 immediately finish itself